# Can't commit to corporate GitLab account

Tags: git, gitlab

I have the following issue:

when i pull the codebase from corporate gitlab repository in Android (Kotlin) and make some changes i can perfectly build and run the application.

But when it comes to commiting and pushing changes this error pops up in Git console:

Execution failed for task ':feature:mainscreen:ktlintCheck'.

> Task :feature:mainscreen:ktlintCheck FAILED
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':feature:mainscreen:ktlintCheck'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

i googled and learned that i need to check my java home path in mac. so when i type "/usr/libexec/java_home -V" in terminal it shows:

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
> 11.0.18 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.18" /Librar/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

I've also discovered that changes in .xml files can be commited without an issue. only .kt files have problems.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it would affect only .kt files because if you look closely at the name of the failed task it mentions `ktlint`. [KtLint](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint) is the linter for the Kotlin language to check the code style and certain rulesets.

Looks like it is configured on Git pre-push(or pre-commit) hook.

Why it's failing?
Usually exit code 1 is for code style violation. Linter is failing itself, which means your newly added Kotlin code is not aligned with the existing code style. Usually, KtLint gives you the exact position in the file where it failed but probably you copied the error from Android Studio notifications.